# Hibernate Micronaut Data JPA: Named parameter not bound : p1

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, psql, micronaut

I'm currently creating a simple application with a psql DB using Micronaut Data, and I'm using a CrudRepository to make queries. However I keep receiving the following error when trying to use the "**findBySymbol**" query :

```
    [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] ERROR io.micronaut.http.server.RouteExecutor - Unexpected error occurred: Named parameter not bound : p1
org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter not bound : p1
```

This is my Entity:

```
 @Entity(name = "quote")
@Table(name = "quote", schema = "mn")
@Data
@Introspected
public class QuoteEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = SymbolEntity.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "symbol", referencedColumnName = "value")
    private SymbolEntity symbol;

    private BigDecimal bid;

    private BigDecimal ask;
    @Column(name = "last_price")
    private BigDecimal lastPrice;

    private BigDecimal volume;
    
}
```

and repository:

```
@Repository
public interface QuotesRepository extends CrudRepository<QuoteEntity, Integer> {

    @Override
    List<QuoteEntity> findAll();

    Optional<QuoteEntity> findBySymbol(SymbolEntity symbol);
}
```

and the controller I'm making the call from:

```
 @Operation(summary = "Returns a quote for the given symbol via JPA fetched from the DB")
    @ApiResponse(content = @Content(mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Invalid symbol")
    @Tag(name = "Quotes")
    @Get("/{symbol}/jpa")
    public HttpResponse getQuoteViaJPA(@PathVariable String symbol) {
        final Optional<QuoteEntity> quote = repository.findBySymbol(new SymbolEntity(symbol));
        if (quote.isEmpty()) {
            final CustomError notFound = CustomError.builder()
                    .status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.getCode())
                    .error(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.name())
                    .message("Quote for symbol not available in DB")
                    .path("/quotes/" + symbol + "/jpa")
                    .build();
            return HttpResponse.notFound(notFound);
        }
        return HttpResponse.ok(quote.get());
    }
```

has anyone got any idea's on where the issue is coming from?

Comment: What version are you using? There was a similar bug in the older version.

Comment: ah yeah! I changed the version from 3.2.2 back to 3.0.0 and that has seemed to resolve the issue. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with 3.2.2 version of Micronaut-data-hibernate-jpa, changing the version back to 3.0.0 seems to have resolved the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I would expect the latest version to have it fixed. Can you please report the issue with a way to reproduce it? Thanks!